# Using an Image as my footer background in CSS

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I would like to know how I can use CSS to set an image as the footer background, I would also like the image to automatically resize depending on the screen resolution. If possible I would also love to make the footer a sticky-footer.
I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance

Comment: And where is the problem? What you have so far?

Comment: I would like to know what have you tried so far. I would also like to see some code. If possible I would also love to see a small snippet which reproduces the problem you are facing. I would really appreciate some effort. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```css
footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/1/");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<footer></footer>
```